# Flask Not updating data from new sql data - Nginx, Uwsgi, Centos7, Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, nginx, flask, wsgi

I have a web reporting tool that I've create with flask that connects to a mysql database which receives it's data from a phone system throughout the day. I had this reporting tool working perfectly fine (Updating numbers as you refreshed the screen or as you logged in.) but now ever since I've added 2 queries and changed my code slightly I'm able to still reach the site but it just doesn't update it's numbers as it used to. The numbers are correct upon restarting my uwsgi service and nginx, but the numbers don't update as time goes on and call come in until the service and nginx are restarted. I'm a noob when it comes to deployments and server maintenance. I'm not sure if I need to close my sql connection somewhere in my code and establish the connection again so we receive updated numbers?
Here is my code, I'll show the uwsgi.py, some parts of my main.py (Especially where I added my 2 queries) and also my nginx.conf ... Here you go...
This is just a bare bones of the project. I really don't think it's in my code buy I could be wrong.
**Main.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://root@localhost:3306/asteriskcdrdb"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
engine = db.engine
connection = engine.connect()

location_to_phone = {
    "TX-Billing": "5123597546",
    "TX-Bee Cave": "5123668568",
    "TX-Central Austin": "5124543781",
    "TX-North Austin": "5128373376",
    "TX-Pflugerville": "5122523700",
    "TX-San Antonio": "2106160448",
    "TX-Steiner Ranch": "5122660007",
    "LA-Baton Rouge": "2553039500",
    "LA-Bossier City": "3187425124",
    "La-Lafayette": "3378392773",
    "La-Old Metairie": "5048362050",
    "La-Shreveport": "3186862021",
    "LA-Uptown": "5048975899"
}

location_to_center = {
    "TX-Billing": {"Front Desk": "7000", "Medical": "7001"},
    "TX-Bee Cave": {"Front Desk": "7040", "Medical": "7041"},
    "TX-Central Austin": {"Front Desk": "7050", "Medical": "7051"},
    "TX-North Austin": {"Front Desk": "6000", "Medical": "7031"},
    "Tx-Pflugerville": {"Front Desk": "7070", "Medical": "7071"},
    "Tx-San Antonio": {"Front Desk": "7060", "Medical": "7061"},
    "Tx-Steiner Ranch": {"Front Desk": "7120", "Medical": "7121"},
    "LA-Baton Rouge": {"Front Desk": "7080", "Medical": "7081"},
    "LA-Bossier City": {"Front Desk": "0", "Medical": "0"},
    "La-Lafayette": {"Front Desk": "7100", "Medical": "7101"},
    "La-Old Metairie": {"Front Desk": "0", "Medical": "0"},
    "La-Shreveport": {"Front Desk": "0", "Medical": "0"},
    "LA-Uptown": {"Front Desk": "0", "Medical": "0"}
}

def reports():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        print("Authenticated")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    form = ReportConfig(prefix='a')
    form2 = Details(prefix='b')
    form3 = ReportConfig2(prefix='c')

    start_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    totals = []
    answered = []
    no_answer = []
    average = []
    client_num = []
    medicals = []
    fronts = []

    calls = 0
    notan = 0
    ans = 0


    for (loc, num), (site, data) in zip(location_to_phone.items(),location_to_center.items()):
        md = data['Medical']
        fd = data['Front Desk']
        test = num


        totalcalls = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND NOT lastapp='background' and calldate between '{start_date} 08:00:00' and '{end_date} 23:59:59'")
        answered_count = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND NOT lastapp='background' AND disposition='ANSWERED' and calldate between '{start_date} 08:00:00' and '{end_date} 23:59:59'")
        no = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND NOT lastapp='background' AND disposition='NO ANSWER' and calldate between '{start_date} 08:00:00' and '{end_date} 23:59:59'")
        av = connection.execute(f"SELECT duration from cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND NOT lastapp='background' AND calldate between '{start_date} 08:00:00' AND '{end_date} 23:59:59'")
        medical = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND NOT lastapp='background' and dst='{md}' and calldate between '{start_date} 08:00:00' and '{end_date} 23:59:59'")
        front_desk = connection.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE did='{test}' AND NOT lastapp='background' and dst='{fd}' and calldate between '{start_date} 08:00:00' and '{end_date} 23:59:59'")
        answer_num = [row[0] for row in answered_count]

        nono = [row[0] for row in no]

        total = [row[0] for row in totalcalls]

        med = [row[0] for row in medical]
        front = [row[0] for row in front_desk]


        sum = 0
        count = total[0]

        calls = calls + total[0]
        notan = notan + nono[0]
        ans = ans + answer_num[0]
        for x in av:
            sum = sum + x[0]

        try:
            avg = (sum/count)
        except:
            avg = 0
        # avg = (sum/count)
        average.append(round(avg, 2))
        totals.append(total[0])
        answered.append(answer_num[0])
        no_answer.append(nono[0])
        client_num.append(test)
        medicals.append(med[0])
        fronts.append(front[0])

return render_template('reports.html', start_date = start_date, month_date = start_date, assign=assign, form=form, form2=form2,  form3=form3, end_date = end_date, all_calls=calls, all_answered=ans, not_answered=notan, location=zip(totals, location_to_phone, answered, no_answer, average, client_num, medicals, fronts))
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from main import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

**itinapinch_rep.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi


master = true
processes = 5


socket = itinapinch_rep.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true


die-on-term = true
```

**itinapinch_rep.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve itinapinch_rep
After=network.target


[Service]
User=reports
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/reports/itinapinch_rep
Environment="PATH=/home/reports/itinapinch_rep/it_venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/reports/itinapinch_rep/it_venv/bin/uwsgi --ini itinapinch_rep.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference, but I think you should create a `connection` per request, and call `connection.close()` when the request is finished.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Perfect I was just about to do that, I read that this was best practice. I’ll let you know if this fixes my problem.

Comment: @snakecharmerb This answered my question, and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html?highlight=connection#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection) for `sqlalchemy.engine.Connection`:

> The Connection object represents a single dbapi connection checked out from the connection pool. In this state, the connection pool has no affect upon the connection, including its expiration or timeout state. For the connection pool to properly manage connections, connections should be returned to the connection pool (i.e. connection.close()) whenever the connection is not in use_.

So rather than being created as a global at import time, connections should be created and closed within the life-cycle of each request.